# how to extract a value of variable from a javascript function in the html page while parsing an html page

Tags: java, javascript, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I have to parse an html page. I have to extract the value of the name element in the below html which is assigned to a javascript function. How do I do it using JSoup.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields.DEPTID.value"/>
```

JS:

```
departmentId.onChange = function(value) {                                       
    var departmentId = dijit.byId("departmentId");

    if (value == null || value == "") {
        document.transferForm.elements["fields.DEPTID.value"].value = "";
        document.transferForm.elements["fields.DEPTID_DESC.value"].value = "";
    } else {
        document.transferForm.elements["fields.DEPTID.value"].value = value;
        document.transferForm.elements["fields.DEPTID_DESC.value"].value = departmentId.getDisplayedValue();

        var locationID = departmentId.store.getValue(departmentId.item, "loctID");
        var locationDesc = departmentId.store.getValue(departmentId.item, "loct");

        locationComboBox = dijit.byId("locationId");

        if (locationComboBox != null) {
            if (locationID != "") {
                setLocationComboBox(locationID, locationDesc);
            } else {
                setLocationComboBox("AMFL", "AMFL - AMY FLORIDA");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to teach you form the top:

```
//Connect to the url, and get its source html
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();

//Get ALL the elements in the page that meet the query
//you passed as parameter. 
//I'm querying for all the script tags that have the
//name attribute inside it
Elements elems = doc.select("script[name]");

//That Elements variable is a collection of
//Element. So now, you'll loop through it, and
//get all the stuff you're looking for
for (Element elem : elems) {
    String name = elem.attr("name");

    //Now you have the name attribute
    //Use it to whatever you need.
}
```

Now if you want some help with the Jsoup querys to get any other elements you might want, here you go the API documentation to help: [Jsoup selector API](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Hope that helped =)

Comment: I need the attribute "name" value from the script. However, I would not the name of script as I have to write a generic parser to parse any html page. I'm not sure how to use the above code as I do not know what to replace the script with. Can you please elucidate the above code.